# como llenar un combo usando un enum, con spring?

Tags: java, spring, enum

Tengo el siguiente enum

```
public enum TipoMovimientos {

MOVIMI_ALTA(1L,"ALTA"),
MOVIMI_BAJA(2L,"BAJA"),
MOVIMI_EXTEM(3L,"EXTEMPORANEO");



private Long idTipoMov;
private String descTipoMov;

private TipoMovimientos(Long idTipoMov, String descTipoMov) {
    this.idTipoMov = idTipoMov;
    this.descTipoMov = descTipoMov;
}
```

}

y quiero mostrar esas tres opciones dentro de un combo, este es mi controller que me direcciona a la pagina

```html
@RequestMapping(value= "/views/consulta", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redireccionaConsultaPage(Locale locale, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(Constantes.CONSULTA_FORM, new Consulta());
        return Constantes.CONSULTA_VISTA;
}
```

pero no se como hacer que se visualice, debe ser dentro de un metodo del controller?

este es mi combo

```html
<select id="tipoMov" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" 
        data-placement="right" title="Movimientos" name="tipoMov">
</select>
<span class="error" path="tipoMov"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

En el controller añades el Enum al modelo:

```
model.addObject("tipoMovimientos", TipoMovimientos.values());
```

En la jsp:

```
<form:select path="selection">
    <form:options items="${tipoMovimientos}" itemValue="idTipoMov" itemLabel="descTipoMov"/>
</form:select>
```

Comment: Ya lo probé , pero es que no agarra las etiquetas <form: select>, y manda error en la página , hay otra manera con las etiquetas así como las puse?

Comment: ¿Estás usando algún motor de plantillas? ¿Cuál?